# jQuery Select2 not displaying Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am stuck at problem where i believe i am getting the response in correct format but i am not able to display the data returned from the server. Intelligent Minds! I need your help.

Below is my HTML code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <select id="owner" class="dropDowns">
        <option value="00000" selected="selected">Select Owner</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

JQuery Code:

This function is getting called with no problems and a result is also returned from the server but some how i am not able to format that result and display it to the user. I am not sure what i am doing wrong and this has been bugging me for quiet some time now.

```
$("#owner").select2({
     minimumInputLength: 3,
      ajax: {
        url: "http://localhost:8080/iam/aexp/rest/ePAAS/getOwner",
        dataType: "jsonp",
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa('spadmin' + ":" + 'admin')
        },
        type: 'GET',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
          return {
            adsId: params.term, // search term

          };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {

          return {
            results: data
          };
        },
        cache: true
      },
      formatResult: function (data) {
                  return "<div>" + data.id + "</div>";
              },
        formatSelection: function (data) {
             return data.id;
        }


    });
```

And here is the response I am getting from the server:

```
[{"id":0,"text":"rgadke"}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks as if your data is in a list and then a dictionary. Try `data[0].id`

Comment: @GaryJohnson I can try that. I read in one of the post it is should be like this only. Below is the link for that post.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160682/select2-ajax-wont-display-json-data-returned

Comment: I actually meant `data[0].id`

Comment: @GaryJohnson No! Didn't work

Comment: You have the opposite issue of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29146743/359284), you _should be using_ `templateResult` but you are using the old `formatResult`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I was not returning the result in the correct JSON format